# How to print 2 columns retrieved from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

Something missing with the code (I guess). I want to show the student id and name in the list box. But I see this:

[image]

I can't figure out the problems especially with the inner join.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strName = "";

    connect.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(" Select Student_tbl.StudentName, Student_tbl.StudentID, Module_tbl.ModuleID FROM[Course-Student] INNER JOIN Student_tbl ON [Course-Student].SID = Student_tbl.StudentID INNER JOIN Module_tbl ON[Course-Student].CID = Module_tbl.ModuleID WHERE(Module_tbl.ModuleID = '" + tbCourse.Text+"')",connect);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
       strName = reader[1].ToString();
       listBox1.Items.Add(strName);
    }

    connect.Close();
}
```

Comment: Don't execute your query twice - first with `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` (this is *totally useless* here, since you're not inserting or deleting anything), and then a second time with the `.ExecuteReader()`. Call **only** what is really needed - here: `ExecuteReader()` since you're returning a result set you want to iterate over.

Comment: Thank you.. very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing retrieving from the reader only the `StudentID` field. Change your `while` loop as follows to retrieve both fields and concatenate the values:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   var name = reader[0].ToString();
   var id = reader[1].ToString();
   listBox1.Items.Add(id + " " + name);
}
```

You can also use [String Interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) (which is C# 6 syntactic sugar for [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)) like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   listBox1.Items.Add($"{reader[1].ToString()} {reader[0].ToString()}");
}
```

Also, as for the sql statement: Do not use string concatenation to create the statement. This is susceptible for SQL Injections. Use instead [Parameterized Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: nice..  very helpful. Sir, how to remove repetition data? for example MOD3 - it shows all the lists that i want but then if I tried to search MOD2, the list from MOD3 did not clear or removed. i did some research but i don't really understand the code. i make also create clear button. private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// CLear BUtton
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }

Comment: @madhiahmahmod - This is a follow-up question and it should be asked in a separate question. If you are working with collections linq's `Distinct()` is a nice thing to use.